# Kernel debugging on host machine under user account

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, wdk

I'm trying to setup environment for kernel debugging and use KMDFDrv sample. Host - win 7 x64 wdk 8.1 vs2013RC, target - win8.1 x64 clean installation (no VM).
Both machines in the same workgroup, both firewalls down, UAC on target down.
User and Admin accounts use same passwords. On target WDKRemoteUsers is also created.

When I'm logged on host as Administrator - no issues. When I'm logged on host under user account I see that in "debugger immediate window" everything stops after reporting "Pass" status for actions that been just made - "driver removal x64", "driver preparation", "driver install", "Driver post install". Code compiled correctly for x64, win 8.1.

I'm not getting kd input window, only "debugging is running" msg.
Attaching to kernel on target also fails under user account. kd doesn't appear.

Initially target machine was provisioned and setup from host using user account. Then under Admin account in VS on host I also added target machine without provisioning.

Is there anything I'm missing? Can I do kernel debugging on target when logged on host under user account?

Comment: Do you require that user account must have limited permissions? Can you simply include that user into administrators group, such that it has the same permissions as administrator?

Comment: @mvp exactly, I can't let that user be an Admin.